# How to instantly display data after an API call in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I don't understand why the second line, which reads data from the props, is not displayed as instantly as the first, i would like them to be displayed instantly
I update the state when a button is clicked, which calls api, data is coming in, the state is updating, but the second line requires an additional press to display
How to display both lines at once after a call? What's my mistake?
I'm using react hooks, and i know that required to use useEffect for re-render component, i know, that how do work asynchronous call,but i'm a little confused, how can i solve my problem, maybe i need to use 'useDeep effect' so that watching my object properties, or i don't understand at all how to use 'useEffect' in my situation, or even my api call incorrectly?

I have tried many different solution methods, for instance using Promise.all, waiting for a response and only then update the state

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./test";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

app.js

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
  import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

  const useDataApi = (initialState) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
    const stateCopy = [...state];

    const setDate = (number, value) => {
      setState(() => {
        stateCopy[number].date = value;
        return stateCopy;
      });
    };

    const setInfo = async () => {
      stateCopy.map((item, index) =>
        getFetch(item.steamId).then((res) => setDate(index, res.Date))
      );
    };

    const getFetch = async (id) => {
      if (id === "") return;
      const requestID = await fetch(`https://api.covid19api.com/summary`);
      const responseJSON = await requestID.json();
      console.log(responseJSON);
      const result = await responseJSON;
      return result;
    };

    return { state, setState, setInfo };
  };

  const Children = ({ data }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <ul>
          {data.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              {item.date ? item.date : "Not data"}
              <br></br>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </>
    );
  };

  const InfoUsers = ({ number, steamid, change }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <input
          value={steamid}
          numb={number}
          onChange={(e) => change(number, e.target.value)}
        />
      </>
    );
  };

  function App() {
    const usersProfiles = [
      { date: "", id: 1 },
      { date: "", id: 2 }
    ];
    const profiles = useDataApi(usersProfiles);

    return (
      <div>
        <InfoUsers number={0} change={profiles.setID} />
        <InfoUsers number={1} change={profiles.setID} />
        <button onClick={() => profiles.setInfo()}>Get</button>
        <Children data={profiles.state} loading={profiles} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default App;
```

To get the data, just click GET
In this example, completely removed useEffect, maybe i don’t understand how to use it correctly.
P.s: Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `stateCopy`, as you have it in the callback of the `setState`:

```
const setInfo = async () => {
  // we want to update the component only once
  const results = await Promise.all(
    state.map(item => getFetch(item.steamId))
  );
  // 's' is the current state
  setState(s =>
    results.map((res, index) => ({ ...s[index], date: res.Date })
  );
};
```

Comment: Oh god..., thanks you very much! It turns out that my mistake is incorrect filling state?   And then it is completely unnecessary stateCopy, we can use prevState, right? Another little question, how to redirect all this to a function later? For example, in function 'setDate'? Or is it undesirable to do this with asynchronous calls? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes your mistake was copying the current state and not property updating the state. I don't understand what you mean by ```how to redirect all this to a function later```